# How to add font in Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, sass

I have a project with Laravel and Vue.js and I use scss. I want to add new font into my project and I can't do this. 
I create file fonts.scss, create a variable with font

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
  src: url(/Proxima-Nova-Bold.otf);
}

$proxima-nova-bold: 'Proxima Nova Bold', sans-serif;
```

And I have console mistake `GET http://local.{my-domain}/Proxima-Nova-Bold.otf net::ERR_ABORTED`

Here is how I import scss file in Vue component

```
@import '../../../fonts/fonts.scss';
```

Here is my laravel mix

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.copy('resources/assets/images', 'public/images', false)
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
```

Where did I make mistake?
Or tell me how to add fonts correctly?

Comment: You told it how to load the font face, and you gave it a path. If that file doesn't exist at `public/Proxima-Nova-Bold.otf`, the client can't request it. Make sure it does.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how can I work only in resources, not public? maybe should I write some rule for webpack?

Comment: Yep. You should use the `file-loader` plugin for this.

Comment: What is your exact build setup for your frontend? laravel mix ? vue-cli ? plain webpack ? For a first guess I don't see any reason of using an absolute path in the url there. Use the relative path and if webpack is setup correctly it will handle resolving and bundling the font correctly.

Comment: @FrankProvost I use laravel mix. Add code snippet to the question

Answer (score 13):

Works for vue3

1. Download the font and place it with other static assets.
2. In app.vue register the font family with @font-face like below:

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: <name_u_choose>;
    src: url('~@/assets/fonts/<static_font_file>.ttf');
}
```

3. Use it in your components like below

```
<style>
<you-selector> {
    font-family: <name_u_chose_before>;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it worked for me without `~` at the start of url: `src: url('@/assets/fonts/<static_font_file>.ttf');`

Answer (score 6):

Based on this issue in the laravel mix github https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1172 laravel mix will copy the fonts automatically when referencing them correctly.

Therefore i suggest to use a relative path when referencing the font. This should actually trigger laravel mix to create a folder "fonts" in your "public" folder

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
  src: url('./../fonts/Proxima-Nova-Bold.otf');
}
```

Comment: this cause an error while building, the only way to run yarn dev is only this way @font-face {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
  src: url(/Proxima-Nova-Bold.otf);
}

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a line like this to your mix file:

```
.copy('resources/fonts', 'public/fonts')
```

Comment: This should not be required when using laravel-mix

Comment: This method imports only scss file, but not the fonts. How could I import fonts files?